# vertical align not working - want content to be in middle of my div

Tags: html, css

im trying to vertically align everything in one div but i cannot work out how to do it as the vertical align css code does not do the job. Im trying to make it so that instead of all the content inside the div being at the top of the div, i want it to be in the center if you know what i mean.

Any help would be appreciated. thanks

HTML:

```
<div id="add_to_cart_box">
<p class="cart_box_small">RRP: £<span style="text-decoration:line-through;">29.99</span></p>
<p class="cart_box_large">Our Price: £19.99</p>
<p class="cart_box_small">YOU SAVE: £10.00 (33%)</p>
<div class="add_to_cart_buttons">Quantity: n Dropdown, BUY BUT</div>
<p class="cart_box_small">FREE UK Delivery. Express delivery services available. In Stock. Same day dispatch if ordered before 2pm.</p>
<p class="cart_box_small">14 DAY MONEY BACK GUARANTEE.</p>
<p class="cart_box_small">3 MONTH  WARRANTY.</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#add_to_cart_box{
    width:300px;
height:230px;
border:1px solid #a0a0a0;
padding: 10px 0 10px 0;
margin: 0 0 0 10px;}

.add_to_cart_buttons{
background:#FF0;
background:#91ae63;
padding:20px 10px 20px 10px;
margin:10px 0 10px 0;
text-align:center;
font-family:arial,verdana,helvetica,sans-serif;
font-size:14px;
color:#333333;
text-decoration:none;
font-weight:bold;
text-transform:uppercase;}

p.cart_box_small{
font-family:arial,verdana,helvetica,sans-serif;
font-size:12px;
color:#333333;
text-decoration:none;
font-weight:100;
padding:0 10px 0 10px;
margin:0;
text-align:center;}

p.cart_box_large{
font-family:arial,verdana,helvetica,sans-serif;
font-size:16px;
color:#333333;
text-decoration:none;
font-weight:bold;
text-transform:uppercase;
padding:5px 10px 5px 10px;
margin:0;
text-align:center;}
```

Comment: Do you want the content inside vertially aligned or the whole box vertically aligned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want everything inside the `div` vertically aligned in the middle.

Try this:

In `#add_to_cart_box`, add:

```
display:table;
```

Inside the `#add_to_cart_box` div, add another `div`. For example: `<div class="center">`

Add this CSS to it:

```
.center{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yLA6b/3/)**

More info **[here](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.html)** for vertical alignment.

**Note:** IE7 and below do not support `display:table;` or `display: table-cell;`

Answer (score -1):

have you tried working with [this](http://zerosixthree.se/vertical-align-anything-with-just-3-lines-of-css/)?

I have updated your css and html just by one wrapping div and 5 css lines [here](http://jsfiddle.net/yLA6b/2/)

html added:

```
<div class="vert_align">***everything needing vertical aligment***</div>
```

css added:

```
.vert_align{
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Comment: i am not seeing anything wrong... could you be more specific?

Comment: Can't say for sure but I think the downvote is because this is a somewhat hackish solution for newer browsers.